# I cannot figure out why this code will not work

Tags: c++

what is wrong with my code here?

```
int main() {
  for(int i=0; i>=5; ++i){

   cout << "Hello World! \n";

  }

  return 0;
}
```

It is supposed to display "Hello World" 5 times.

Comment: You have to be more careful. That's the reason! for example, look the i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is replace the `>=` with `<=` because you are saying that `i` is greater than 5 already. Also, with this for loop it will display "Hello World" 6 times because you have `i` starting at 0.

Comment: He only made one error, not two. Your error is using a too convoluted correction.

Comment: His answer wasn't convoluted, I can follow it but because I just started out in C++ I can't see errors like this right off the bat. I appreciate the help and I didn't even realize it would print out 6 times instead of 5 until he pointed it out.